# Get time elapsed of a video

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `VideoCapture`, then I am performing some actions such as object detection. Now I have reached a stage where I want to get the elapsed time of the video during a specific time, for instance when an object is detected. What is the best/most reliable way to get the elapsed time?

The important thing is that the video is not running at original speed due to FPS drop, this is because I am performing some image processing. So the problem is that I want to be able to get the time in the processed video and then be able to track the time in the orignal video and it should be on the same sequence. (Example: I get the time 05:30, then it should be in the same place in the original video if I go to 05:30 in VLC etc.).

I hope i'm clear enough in the explanation. I have tried `CV_CAP` with different options but I don't get how I could get the time. The usage of this will be something like:

```
if (this)
   Get time elapsed
```

Any ideas and **all** help is **very** **appreciated**!

Comment: It's not clear: is this happening in real time or is this post-processing of a video that could occur completely independent of original frame rate?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you know the original FPS rate and the current frame number, then it's trivial: `elapsed_time_in_seconds = frame_number / original_fps`.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV decodes a video to its frames no matter the CODEC of the videofile. The module responsible for that is ffmpeg, which is a mess and out of the scope of image processing in the content of research. What I mean is that OpenCV does not care if you can't get the real fps of the CODEC. As a consequence, there is no guaranteed way to obtain the timings you're asking. As @Jesper said, try to be lucky with original_fps (which is a constant number, and as you may know videos may have varying FPS, e.g. live streaming video changes its fps according to the available network bandwidth to catch up time).

It may sound silly, but the most trustworthy way to infer about time in OpenCV is to actually hardprint the time stamp on the frame during video capturing.

Another solution could it be to set preconditions/requirements for your software. E.g. require that video input should be of constant 30 FPS.

Finally, as all others do, use frame number for time indication.